# Fedora 25 medialess installation

Tags: fedora, partition, system-installation, unmounting

Trying to install Fedora 25 on my laptop. I was still running an old Fedora 20.

However, I can't burn a DVD and I don't have access to a USB media either.

So, I tried with [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/196933/how-to-boot-linux-iso-images-directly-from-your-hard-drive/) method . It works perfectly until I have to properly install Fedora. The installation tool requires me to `umount /dev/sda2` which is my `/home` partition. If I `umount` the partition I don't see how to system is going to be able to read from the ISO file.

Do you have any ideas? Any trick I could use? I really don't want to burn a CD.

Comment: Create a new partition e,g sda5 size= 5G , move your iso to it then modify the line on `40_custom` to `loopback loop (hd0,5)$isofile`

Comment: Not an answer, but you may also be able to simply upgrade without media. Use dnf to update to Fedora 21 (instructions [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading_Fedora_using_package_manager) and then use [dnf system upgrade](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF_system_upgrade) to go to F25. However, is not being able to get to media a temporary condition or a permanent one? I'd be concerned about taking such a long jump without _some_ fallback boot method.